# Как изменить переменную php по событию onclick?

Tags: php, javascript

Как изменить переменную php по событию onclick?
Есть код php который добавляет из файла значения в select

```
<?php
$file = 'list.txt';
$arr = file($file);
$count = count($arr);
echo '<select name="sll">';
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
 echo '<option value="'.trim($arr[$i]).'">'.trim($arr[$i]).'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

как правильно сделать что бы добавить перед этим кодом 2 кнопки при нажатии на которые менялось бы название файла в этой строке:

```
$file = 'list.txt';
```

и соответственно в select подгружались бы значения из другого файла.

Comment: Надеюсь вы понимаете, что JS работает в браузере пользователя, а php на стороне сервера. И переменная в php не изменится ни при каких действиях на странице. Когда на клиенте нужно что бы в php что то отработало - он шлет новый HTTP-запрос, запускается php файл, с нуля. Анализирует переданные параметры и уже решает что делать

Comment: естественно я это понимаю, решение уже нашел, спасибо